# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Writing's [second moderator election](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three new moderators are:

[image: F1Krazy] [image: motosubatsu] [image: linksassin]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4787408659808256/0).

Comment: Congratulations you guys!! I am thrilled to have new mods here, and all three of you are perfect fits. I think this heralds an exciting new phase of Writing SE.

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations to the three of you!!!

You are all going to do great.

Answer (score 6):

## Thanks for the opportunity

I'd like to thank the community for supporting us in this new phase for the site. I'm hoping we can all give back to this community and make it into something truly great.

To F1Krazy and motosubatsu, congratulations! I look forward to working with you.

To Kit Z. Fox, thankyou for running. Without you this wouldn't really have been a proper election.

Finally, thankyou to Catija and the other CMs for organizing this and giving this community a chance to recover.

Comment: I am relieved I lost and glad that the site will continue. Thanks for running!